# array of UInt16, what's the suffix in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, uint16

I'm trying to initialize inline an array of UInt16. For int I can do the following:

```
int[] int_array = new[]{0,0,0,0};
```

meanwhile using UInt16 doesn't work without a cast:

```
UInt16[] uint16_array= new[]{(UInt16)0,(UInt16)0};
```

It's quite annoying do those casts. 
I was wondering if there is any suffix in C# to disambiguate the assignment (like 0.0f for float).

Comment: I wish C# would have suffixes for `short`s! It seems only fair, since `long`s are `L`. Maybe there is a reason that I am unaware of.

Comment: No need for the casts. And to my knowledge, there isn't a suffix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there is one, but why don't you do this instead

```
UInt16[] uint16_array= new UInt16[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Comment: `ushort` would be preferable, IMO. But other that that, agreed.

Comment: @Lasse d'oh! indeed. Fixed ;p

Comment: This is correct, there is no shortcut prefix. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbf1574z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). UInt16 is the same as ushort, BTW.

Comment: +1: thanks..sorry for the simple question but I'm learning C# these days :)

Answer (score 5):

C# doesn't have a type suffix for unsigned 16-bit integers. VB.NET does though, just for reference:

```
Dim number As UShort = 8US
```

Here's [another resource](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/08/secrets-and-lies-of-type-suffixes-in-c-and-vb-net/) that lists the different suffixes.

Comment: @Marlon: Right you are; I've rearranged my answer in case some poor soul stumbles upon it in the future.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ They should bring this to C# .NET asap.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an even shorter way than Corey's:

```
ushort[] uint16_array = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

(or)

```
UInt16[] uint16_array = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=VS.71).aspx

Unfortunately no suffix for short.